# jQuery's usage of return !1 or return !0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm seeing quite a bit of usage of `!0` and `!1` within the source code for jQuery and Telerks' JS. I've most seen it in return statements which may have some bearing on it's usage.

What is the purpose? Is this some sort of optimization?

[image: Example from Kendo]

Comment: It's minified. Less bytes means a smaller script which means potentially faster load time. This is one of the optimizations that the [Google closure compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) performs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a trick for minifying:

```
!0 === true
!1 === false
```

It just does the same thing with less characters.

Comment: `1` or `0` itself isn't enough? Why negate it?

Comment: @FrankV So that a `boolean` is returned. `typeof 0 === "number"` whereas `typeof !0 === "boolean"`.

Comment: True, I should make those `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1):

I guess technically it is an optimization, but not one I encourage you to do by hand. a minifier will do this for you.

It's simply to return a boolean value.

```
!0 == true // because 1 is true, 0 is false, so NOT 0 is true.
!1 == false // same as above logic but flipped.
```